# using Keycloak with icCube - how to get it to work (missing Keycloak context token)?

Tags: keycloak, iccube

I am trying to use Keycloak in front of icCube and encounter some issues. May be someone could help.

**Done so far:**

- installed icCube on a Linux - Debain 10 system, 8Gb as a Virtual Machine in VMWare (following advice in https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/running_iccube/server_linux.php)
- created two roles: IC3_admin (all access) and IC3_sales (access to cube sales)
- changed icCube.xml in accordance with https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/configuring_iccube/authentication_keycloak.php
- installed keycloak on the same server

with regard to keycloak:

- created Realm icCube and client iccube, with 2 users: admin and user
- created 2 roles: admin and sales

the json file is:

```
  {
  "realm": "icCube",
  "auth-server-url": "http://192.168.178.32:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "iccube",
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "credentials": {
    "secret": ".... secret ...."
  },
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "policy-enforcer": {}
}
```

Now when I restart icCube after the icCube.xml change and try to logon I get the error in the log:

```
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (12-07-19 15:14:35.560 CEST) [auth] Keycloak auth. started
[               qtp689602108-25] [ERROR] (12-07-19 15:14:35.581 CEST) [auth] missing Keycloak context token
```

How to solve this error? I guess it has something to do with the set-up in Keycloak, but I can not figure out what exactly?

**additional info from the log**
It is a bit too much to put the complete log here, but these might be interesting lines:

```
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:02.891 CEST)       filter mapping : Keycloak OIDc
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:02.891 CEST)                      : crazydev.iccube.ux.processor.servlet.UxRestApiServlet-348ad293
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:02.891 CEST)       filter mapping : Passthrough
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:02.891 CEST)                      : crazydev.iccube.ux.processor.servlet.UxRestApiServlet-348ad293
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:02.891 CEST)       filter mapping : HTTP Basic Authentication
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:02.892 CEST)                      : crazydev.iccube.server.xmla.IcCubeXmlaOverHttpHandler-30f74e79
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:02.892 CEST)       filter mapping : Keycloak OIDc
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:02.892 CEST)                      : crazydev.iccube.gwt.server.reporting.component.OlapReportingServlet-2c88a3e8
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:02.892 CEST)       filter mapping : Passthrough
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:02.892 CEST)                      : crazydev.iccube.gwt.server.reporting.component.OlapReportingServlet-2c88a3e8
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:02.892 CEST)       filter mapping : Keycloak OIDc
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:02.892 CEST)                      : crazydev.iccube.server.gvi.GviServlet-68ac9ec5
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:02.892 CEST)       filter mapping : Passthrough
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:02.892 CEST)                      : crazydev.iccube.server.gvi.GviServlet-68ac9ec5
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:02.892 CEST)       filter mapping : GVI Authentication (logout)
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:02.892 CEST)                      : crazydev.iccube.server.gvi.GviServlet-68ac9ec5
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:02.892 CEST)       filter mapping : Print Authentication
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:02.892 CEST)                      : crazydev.iccube.server.print.IcCubePrintServlet-a50d709

[                          main] [DEBUG] (12-07-19 15:14:03.521 CEST) Use authServerUrl: http://192.168.178.32:8080/auth, tokenUrl: http://192.168.178.32:8080/auth/realms/icCube/protocol/openid-connect/token, relativeUrls: NEVER
[                          main] [ INFO] (12-07-19 15:14:03.543 CEST) [keycloak] Keycloak is using a per-deployment configuration.
[                          main] [DEBUG] (12-07-19 15:14:03.545 CEST) [auth] passthrough : configured
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
missing Keycloak context token
```

means the Keycloak authentication has not been performed.

It is more likely that something went wrong with the Keycloak actual authentication.

Hint: ensure you did pass the step where you get redirected to the Keycloak server authentication page when attempting to log into the icCube server.

Comment: I found it, the documentation says that you can not use the linke /icCube/icCube.html and use /icCube/console instead. This "error" just set me on the worng foot.